# Ansible does not ask user for prompts

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get an ansible script to prompt the user. I have the following script:

```
   - name: Generate a new SSH Key
     shell: ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C {{email_address}}
```

When I run from command line, it ask for a passphrase and file location. When I run from the ansible, it uses the default values. How do I get it to pause, so that it asks the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

Write an Expect script, copy it to the destination machine and execute it

or

Use Ansible's [Expect](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html) module

```
- expect:
  command: ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C {{email_address}}
  responses:
    'Enter file in which .*': '/home/gibson/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

or

Specify non-interactive ssl-keygen

```
- shell: ssh-keygen -f myfile.rsa -t rsa -b 4096 -C {{email_address}} -N ''
```

or

Use Ansible's [vars_prompt](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_prompts.html) to prompt for the value and pass it to the command

```
vars_prompt:
  - name: "key_file_name"
    prompt: "Enter file in which to save the key: "
    ...
    ...
tasks:
  - shell: ssh-keygen -f {{key_file_name}} -t rsa -b 4096 -C {{email_address}} -N ''
```